# How do I cache and clear the output buffer in Perl?

Tags: php, perl, syntax, porting, output-buffering

I have the following PHP code which opens the output buffer, includes a file, stores it in a variable, and clears the buffer:

```
ob_start(); 
include('test.html');
$input=ob_get_clean();
```

How would the equivalent look in Perl?

Comment: Check out perlvar on this page and search for the `$|` as stated below in the answer. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special variable `$|` . When set to nonzero, does a buffer flush after every write or print

Answer (score 4):

`$| = 1;` will turn on disable buffering for the currently selected handle (`STDOUT` by default). In other words,

```
$| = 1;
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
use IO::Handle qw( );   # Not needed since 5.14.
select()->autoflush(1);
```

which usually means

```
use IO::Handle qw( );   # Not needed since 5.14.
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

So the equivalent would be:

```
# open a file handle try to get test.html
open(my $fh, "<", "test.html") ||
   die 'Could not open test.html: '.$!;
# return the currently selected filehandle
select($fh);
#clear the output buffer
select()->autoflush(1);
```

**References**

- [perldoc: open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)
- [perldoc: keywords](http://learn.perl.org/docs/keywords.html)
- [IO::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/File.html)
- [How do I flush/unbuffer an output filehandle? Why must I do this?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=How%20do%20I%20flush%2Funbuffer%20an%20output%20filehandle%3F%20Why%20must%20I%20do%20this%3F)
- [Flushing Output](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch07_13.htm)